# Adding active menu item class to link ASP

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a pretty basic list of menu items on my asp web page. Currently I am trying to figure out how I could apply a class to the menu item that the user is currently on.

For instance in html it would be something along these lines:

`<li class = "active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>`

My ASP menu is shown below:

```
 <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Screenshots.aspx" Text="Screenshots"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Technology.aspx" Text="Technology"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Contact.aspx" Text="Contact"/>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
```

This is the CSS style I would like to apply to the current menu item based on the page the user is on

```
.current
{
 background:#40AD36;
 color:#fff;   
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Based on the comments guys I've made the following changes to my menu but still no change...

```
  <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" DynamicSelectedStyle-CssClass ="current"  StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="current" >
```

Comment: Are you determining what page the user is on via code?

Comment: Not at the moment, I am unsure how I could do that but if it is the recommended way I would have no problem implementing it.

Comment: Have you looked at this : `DynamicSelectedStyle-CssClass="StaticSelectedStyle"`. Also reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.dynamicselectedstyle.aspx

Comment: MSDN article on using CSS with the control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366731%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

On the properties window of Visual Studio find `StaticSelectedStyle` and put your styles there.